# Duvida Charts Google com Loop

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google

Bom dia,
 Estou usando um chart do google para criar um painel,só que esta me trazendo somente um resultado o meu loop não esta dando certo,alguém poderia me ajudar a ver o que esta errado ?

```
<?php
include("conecta.php");
  $consumo_atual = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Arduino.Leitura");  
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consumo_atual)) {
     $v_data =$linha["Data"]; 
     $v_consumo =$linha["Consumo"]; 
     } 
  ?> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['DATA', 'COSUMO'],
          ['<?php echo "$v_data"; ?>', <?php echo "$v_consumo"; ?>]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Perfomace de Consumo',
          hAxis: {title: 'Consumo Atual',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Preciso trazer todos os resultados pois esse chart e de linha.

Segue alteração:

```
<?php
include("conecta.php");
  $consumo_atual = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Leitura");  
  $v_data_consumo[] = array('DATA', 'CONSUMO');
  while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consumo_atual)) {
  $v_data_consumo[] = array($linha["Data"], $linha["Consumo"]); 
 } 
?>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?php echo json_encode($v_data_consumo); ?>]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Perfomace de Consumo',
          hAxis: {title: 'Consumo Atual',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Vale uma lidinha: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql), assim você irá  compreender esse erro `deprecated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse bloco:

```
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consumo_atual)) {
     $v_data =$linha["Data"]; 
     $v_consumo =$linha["Consumo"]; 
     }
```

deve ser:

```
$v_data_consumo[] = array('DATA', 'CONSUMO');
 while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consumo_atual)) {
     $v_data_consumo[] = array($linha["Data"], $linha["Consumo"]); 
 }
```

Permitindo criar 2 arrays, um de data e um de consumo, com os valores retornados.

A linha:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['DATA', 'COSUMO'],
      ['<?php echo "$v_data"; ?>', <?php echo "$v_consumo"; ?>]
    ]);
```

também deverá ser alterada para algo como:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($v_data_consumo); ?>);
```

Teste e passe feedback...

Comment: Não consegui entender esse erro que gerou: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/html/arduino/conecta.php on line 5

Comment: Não é erro, é warning, mas isso não tem haver com o problema do código, é outra questão, e não deve impedir que o sistema seja executado normalmente. Tente substituir a função “mysql_connect” pela função “mysqli_connect” na linha do arquivo indicado na mensagem de erro.

Comment: Alterei mais ainda não da certo,minha pagina esta voltando vazia,acrescentei na pergunta a alteração.

Comment: Perceba que a ultima alteração vc fez errado e deve estar gerando erro no navegador! Você deve substituir as 4 linhas por apenas uma! Do código alterado que você acrescentou, remova 3 linhas abaixo disso:
"var data = google.visualization.arrayToDa..."

Comment: Putis,cada hora um novo erro,já não estou entendendo... Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string×

Comment: Tente assim essa linha:
google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?php echo json_encode($v_data_consumo); ?>], false);


O false no final é pra reconhecer a primeira posição do arrai como titulos e não dados.

Comment: mesmo erro acima.

Comment: Uma ultima tentativa de minha parte, que testando aqui eu vi que pode estar causando problema, é remover os '[' e ']' desa ultima linha da resposta, como eu já fiz na resposta. Tenta isso.

Comment: Sem sucesso,vou ler melhor a biblioteca do google apps e retorno.